# Is a multivariable function continuous iff it is continuous with respect to each variable?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I am very uncertain when it comes to understanding the continuity of multivariable functions.

If we have, for example, a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{4} \to \mathbb{R}$, and we denote the four variables $x,y,z,w$, are the following statements equivalent?

> i) $f$ is continuous
>
> ii) $f|_{x}, f|_{y}, f|_{z}, f|_{w}$ are each continuous

Here, $f|_{x}$ stands for the function attained by fixing the variables $w,y,z$.  I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: You may use epsilon-delta definition for continuity. See $|f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)|= |f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_1)+f(x_2,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)| $

Answer (score 10):

It is true that if $f$ is continuous, then it is continuous viewed as a function of each of its variables separately. But the converse is false.

For example, let 
$$
g(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}, & \text{if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$;} \\
0, & \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0)$.}
\end{cases}
$$

Then is $g$ is continuous everywhere except $(0,0)$, even though it is continuous viewed in terms of each of its variables separately. To see that it is discontinuous at $(0,0)$, consider its limit at $(0,0)$ along each of the lines $x=0$, $y=0$, and $y = x$.

If you require an example in four variables, write $f(x,y,z,w) = g(x,y)$.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  When you defined $g(x,y)$, are you saying $g|_{x}$ is continuous except at $x = 0$ and $y = 0$?  Also, $g|_{y}$ is continuous except at $x = y$ and $y = 0$?  And $g$ as a function of $x$ and $y$ is continuous except at $(0,0)$?  Why is this a counterexample?

Comment: @layman $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x, 0) = \lim_{y \to 0} g(0, y) = 0$ but $\lim_{t \to 0} g(t, t) = \frac{1}{2}$